# Google Cloud Tar Without Leaving the Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-storage

If I want to move files from a nearline to a coldline bucket and I want to tar the files during the move, is that possible?

I’m using gsutil and the `-zZ` flags, but I can’t get them to do what I’m asking for above. That makes me think they are just doing the gzip during the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The `z` and `Z` flags [apply gzip encoding to those files, but those files maintain the `Content-Type` they had](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options).

(Note: The options for [`mv`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#options) are the same as `cp` has, minus the `R` flag)

The key aspect here is that the files are given a Content-Encoding header set to `gzip`, indicating that the files are compressed on the servers.

If you want to save those files as `tar` files, you would have to compress them as such before moving, either manually, with a script, etc.